# AFNetworking - get response content length

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am using a simple AFNetworking [AFHTTPRequestOperation -initWithRequest:] for downloading file, I would like to check for the response header "content length" before I can actually download the file.
How can I check for response content length in AFNetworking ?

Comment: afnetworking is open source project, so i think that you can update - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection __unused *)connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response method of AFURLConnectionOperation.m, it just uses simple NSURLConnection, you can add property with block that will be called in didReceiveResponse method, and cancel request:  @property (nonatomic, copy) YourBlockType didReciveLengthCallback;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using **expectedContentLength** Property of [NSURLResponse](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html) You can you can find length.

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"Content-lent: %lld", [operation.response expectedContentLength]);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```